# Add two array of arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]];
b = [[5,6],[7,8]];
```

I want the resultant array to be their sum, i.e.,

```
c = [[6,8],[10,12]];
```

Would there be an elegant way to do so?

**Note:**

I currently know that to simply add `a = [1,2]` with `b = [3,4]` to get `c = [4,6]` I need to do

```
c = [a,b].transpose.map{|x| x.reduce(:+)};
```

but I'm not sure how to, if possible, extend this to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.zip(b).map { |x,y| x.zip(y).map { |s| s.inject(:+)  } }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
c = [a, b].transpose.map{|ary| ary.transpose.map{|ary| ary.inject(:+)}}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, with better expression for manipulating numbers, would be to use 'narray'

```
require 'narray'
a = NArray[[1,2],[3,4]]
b = NArray[[5,6],[7,8]]

c = a + b
```

. . . yes really, `c = a + b` and it is much faster too.

You do pay for this though - NArray expects all the elements to contain the same type of object. If that's the case, and especially if your real-world problem has much larger matrices, then I highly recommend `narray` for handling this kind of data